# Big Euclidean norm?

Tags: math-mode, equations, symbols

I would like to replace the Euclidean norm and the first pair of brackets with bigger  ones but I get errors. Can you help me to fix it?

```
 \documentclass[11 pt,a4paper,oneside,openany, notitlepage]{article}
    \input epsf
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics}
    \newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
    \newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}
    \newcounter{mathematicapage}
    \marginparwidth 0pt
    \oddsidemargin 0pt
    \evensidemargin 0pt
    \marginparsep 0pt
    \linespread{1.5}
    \topmargin 0pt
    \textwidth 6.5in
    \textheight 8.5 in

    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    Q(\theta):= \|(a,b,c) \|^2
    \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please reduce the example to the minimum necessary for explaining the problem?

Comment: @ egreg: Hi, actually I think is the complexity of the expression that makes me getting errors when I try to increase the fontsize of the Euclidean norm and of the first pair of brackets.

Comment: @ Niel de Beaudrap: Hi get the small Euclidean norm

Comment: Are you really sure people would be able to read such a complicated formula? You should also do a revision of your preamble that seems a stratification of other preambles, with numerous sins, starting from `\input epsf`.

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example:

```
 Q(\theta):= \Big\|(a,b,c) \Big\|^2
```

There is `\big`, `\bigg`, `\Big`, and  `\Bigg`

Comment: I would like also to increase at the same time the size of the brackets.

Comment: use `\big(` or one of the other

Comment: Isn't it better to use `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` instead of `\Big`?

Comment: `\bigl) ... \bigr(` would make sense

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you load the `mathtools` package and define a new macro, say `\norm`, as follows:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
```

While doing so incurs (slight) setup cost, it has several important advantages:

- Your code will become more readable (and easier to debug...) because you'll be writing things like `\norm{(a,b,c)}^2`, which focuses attention on the *meaning* rather than on its appearance.
- The fence symbols will grow automatically with the contents of the macro if you use the "starred" version of the `\norm` command, which is set up automatically when you execute `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`:

  ```
  \[ \norm*{ \frac{a+c}{u+v} } \]
  ```
- If you don't like the automatically generated size of the "fences" produced by `\norm*`, you can exercise full manual control, e.g., by typing

  ```
  \[ \norm[\bigg]{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_i(x)} \]
  ```

  (Note that the fence produced by `\norm*` would be too big in the present case.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}
\[ Q(\theta)\coloneqq \norm{(a,b,c)}^2\]
\[ \norm*{ \frac{a+c}{u+v} } \]
\[ \norm[\bigg]{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_i(x)} \]
\end{document}
```