# Code for the Notation of Vector Projections?

Tags: vector

What LaTex code do I use to get the notation on the left of this equation, that is the projection of  vector a on vector v?

http://rypress.com/tutorials/mathml/media/vectors-and-functions/summary.png

Comment: How about `\DeclareMathOperator{\proj}{proj}` from the `amsmath` package in preamble and `\[
\proj_\mathbf{v}\mathbf{a} = \]` in the document?

Comment: Oh, and [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Yes thank you! I tried \[proj_  a u\]  and that seems to work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169557/5764
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\newcommand{\vectorproj}[2][]{\textit{proj}_{\vect{#1}}\vect{#2}}
\newcommand{\vect}{\mathbf}

\begin{document}

\[
  \vectorproj[v]{a} = \frac{\vect{a} \cdot \vect{v}}{\norm{\vect{v}}^2} \vect{v}
\]

\end{document}
```

`\vectorproj[<onvector>]{<ofvector>}` can be supplied with an optional `<onvector>`.

Comment: Using the above code, there is no  magnitude parentheses on the v^2 component. I tried addting the box notation |:|: :|:| but that wouldnyt work either. Do you know how to get the correct parentheses on the v^2 term?

Comment: @LlewyThomas: What do you mean by "the correct parentheses"?

Comment: this 
![](http://s30.postimg.org/mual01i9p/Capture1.jpg)
rather than this:
![](http://s10.postimg.org/txv12xo3p/Capture2.jpg)

Comment: @LlewyThomas: If you want to expand the `\norm` delimiters, then you can use `\norm[\big]{..}`, or `\norm[\bigg]{..}`. However, it's not needed (in my opinion) for `\norm{\vect{v}^2}` nor `\norm{\vect{b}}^2`.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? (sorry I've only just started with LaTex)
Do you mean placing something like this in the preamble;

'\newcommand{\norm}[\bigg]'

Comment: If you really want it in italics, use `\mathit` and not `\textit`. Anyway, you should use `\DeclareMathOperator\vectorprojop{\mathit{proj}}` and then define `\vectorproj` in terms of `\vectorprojop`. I can't see the usefulness of defining `\vectorproj` with two arguments, though.

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you may want the projection typeset as an operator (not italic), you can declare a new operator with the `\DeclareMathOperator{}{}` from the `amsmath` package. Inspired by Werners answer I threw in a macro for a projection command.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\proj}{proj}
\newcommand{\vct}{\mathbf}
\newcommand{\vctproj}[2][]{\proj_{\vct{#1}}\vct{#2}}

\begin{document}
\[
\vctproj[v]{a} = \frac{\vct{a}\cdot\vct{v}}{\lVert\vct{v}\rVert^2}\vct{v}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn't add the formatting information to `\vecproj`: the document should have a macro for vectors, say `\newcommand{\vct}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}`, and the input for the projection should be `\proj_{\vct{v}}\vct{a}`: don't hide information.

Comment: I agree. Updating!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible solution if one wants to have `\proj_{#1}{#2}` and `\rej_{#1}{#2}` as macros for vector projection and rejection respectively. I've also added starred variants for both macros.

[image: \proj_{#1}{#2}, \proj*{#1}{#2}, \rej{#1}{#2}, \rej*_{#1}{#2}]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{scalerel} % For \stretchrel
\ifdefined\NewDocumentCommand\else\usepackage{xparse}\fi

\renewcommand{\vec}{\mathbf}
\DeclareMathOperator{\vectorprojection}{proj}
\NewDocumentCommand{\proj}{s e{_} m}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{#3_{\stretchrel*{\parallel}{\perp}#2}}{\vectorprojection_{#2}#3}
}
\DeclareMathOperator{\vectorrejection}{oproj}
\NewDocumentCommand{\rej}{s e{_} m}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{#3_{\perp #2}}{\vectorrejection_{#2}#3}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
    \verb|\proj_{\vec{b}}{\vec{a}}|: & \(\proj_{\vec{b}}{\vec{a}}\) \\
    \verb|\proj*_{\vec{b}}{\vec{a}}|: & \(\proj*_{\vec{b}}{\vec{a}}\) \\
    \verb|\rej_{\vec{b}}{\vec{a}}|: & \(\rej_{\vec{b}}{\vec{a}}\) \\
    \verb|\rej*_{\vec{b}}{\vec{a}}|: & \(\rej*_{\vec{b}}{\vec{a}}\)
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```