# Placement of nested sub- and superscript

Tags: positioning, subscripts, superscripts

When Typesetting some expressions containing sub-/superscripts as sub-/superscript, I observed that the placement of the nested sub-/superscript changes.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \[
        L^p \quad \|.\|_{L^p} \quad \|.\|^{L^p}
    \]
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image: Output of MWE]

---

You'll notice, that the positioning of `p` relative to `L` differs in all three expressions. Similar behaviour can be observered when considering `L_q`.

While I have found several questions on how to control the exacet positioning of "simple" (i.e. non-nested) sub-/superscripts, I couldn't quite figure out, what causes this behaviour and how one can maybe avoid it.

---

- Do you know, why this is happening? Does it maybe have something to do with font properties or some lower level spacing definitions of LaTeX?
- Is there a way to ensure that the relative positioning remains intact when the expression itself is a sub-/superscript?
- Or should I better leave this be b/c one should not fiddle with spacing too much?

Answer (score 1):

I share your concerns. I often end up adding phantom subscripts in these case, which can be added to make the appearance more uniform. (In the presence of a subscript, the superscript moves up.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\PP}{_{\vphantom{Lg}}}
\begin{document}
    \[
        L\PP^p \quad \left\|.\right\|_{L\PP^p} \quad \|.\|^{L\PP^p}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

A bit off-topic, but you may want to use `\norm` from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169565/194703) for the norm.